# Query to find Maximum friends not giving correct resuts

Tags: sqlite

Table Schema for the `Likes` table:

```
id id1
1  2
1  3
2  1
```

I count the total number of Likes for each student with this:

```
select id,count(*)
from friends
group by id
```

I have to find the students with the maximum number of Likes, so I use this query as a temp table:

```
select * from (
  select f1.id,count(*) as count1
  from Likes f1
  group by id
) temp
where not exists (
  select f2.id,count(asterick) as count2
  from Likes f2 group by f2.id having count2 > temp.count1
)
```

It returns all of the records. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong in this query?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) either here or via [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @NickChammas The fiddle in my answer reproduces the problem. Not sure what version of SQLite it uses though. Perhaps it's valid for a bug report.

Comment: @ypercube Nope, I gave up on it after I posted this question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is correct and works fine in other DBMS (SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle, MySQL). In SQLite, it appears there is a bug, possibly due to the correlated subquery and/or the grouping in both the main and the sub query. Here is another way to write the query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count1
FROM Likes
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
      ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM Likes
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY cnt DESC
          LIMIT 1
      ) ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6fc9a/5)**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly this is a simplified query to get your results, although when I tested yours it worked fine as well.  The simplified one may point out a way to get the correct results in your real query with any luck.

```
WITH Totals AS (SELECT id, COUNT(1) AS count1 
                FROM Likes GROUP BY id)
SELECT *
FROM Totals f1
WHERE count1 = (SELECT MAX(count1) FROM Totals)
```

Comment: The query seems correct but have you tested it in SQLite? I don't think sqlite has CTEs.